# callback for twebbrowser delphi

Tags: delphi, callback, twebbrowser

I was wondering how i could make a callback function for the twebbrowser in delphi. I want it to recognize which input or edit box i am clicking in with the mouse..... any ideas?

As requested, hereby the update of the question, the user workflow.
The user would
1. select the inputfield on the twebbrowser by mouse. (the program would see what the information is about this inputfield(value, id, etc.....)
2. fill in the field with prefered information (name, password, whatever really)

At the same time this text is linked back into a memo box. That whould be the start, if i understand this it would be a good beginnning.

Answer (score 1):

Will this code help you?

http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=4#calling-delphi

The article is about calling Delphi-code from JavaScript.

Comment: sadly no, because i suppose i am going the other way. I have a browser, now i want to find out the information about the input box i click with the mouse. hope anyone can help, It's very simple, click in a input box and i want to recognize with delphi the information about that input box. so i can add values....

Comment: What kind of information would you like to get?  The name, the value, id, width, height?  Could you update your question and give an example or describe the users work flow?

Comment: the name value and id would be most important. I have updated the question. hope it makes more sense.